# Wrong Perl version in cgi-bin

Tags: cpanel, perlbrew

Using CloudLinux OS

I have installed Perlbrew using cPanel account terminal.
I have installed perl V5.16.3 and switched it.
If I use 'perl -v' in cPanel account terminal then V5.16.3 is showing correct.
If I put a 'version.pl' file in the cgi-bin it shows V5.26.3 (the system perl version)

I have appended 'source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc' in '.bash_profile'

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Problem resolved.
The shebang in the version.pl was looking at usr/bin/perl
So it correctly reported the system Perl version